# Is there a gulp plugin that can create empty folder / sub-folder structures?

Tags: gulp

I have two environment folders:

- `src` (where development happens)
- `staging` (where pre-production/testing happens)

My gulp project initially deletes everything, including files folders and sub-folders, from the `staging` directory leaving `staging` completely empty. Then before the proceeding build tasks begin (processing and copying various files from `src` to `staging`) I'd like to run a gulp task that creates the necessary folders/sub-folders structure within `staging`. This folders creation task should return a stream so that the next gulp task knows when to begin (I use the `gulp run-sequence` plugin for scheduling synchronous tasks.)

But despite searching for some time I cannot seem to find a simple gulp plugin/technique for creating directory structures without first piping though files via `gulp.src`. Any advice/pointers please?

I have considered using node's mkdir but that doesn't return a stream and would like to keep everything running though gulp if that makes sense.

Many thanks